# Beads on a Bracelet

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can 1 blue bead, 7 red beads and 12 green beads be arranged on a bracelet or turnover necklace?

There are 20 beads so to my mind the answer is $\frac{19!}{1!\cdot7!\cdot12!\cdot2} = 25194$

However, in the OEIS A141783: *number of bracelets (turn over necklaces) with n beads: 1 blue, 12 green, and r = n - 13 red*, the number is given as **25236** for the case where n=20 (where there are 7 red beads). The formula given to support this is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{n-1}{12} + \binom{\frac{n-2 + n\bmod 2}{2}}{6}$$

This becomes, in the case of $n=20$:

$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{19}{12} + \binom{18}{6} = 25236$$

I don't understand this formula and the result is 42 more than the previous result. Can anybody clarify what the current answer to this problem is?

OEIS link: http://oeis.org/A141783

Answer (score 3):

You have divided by two without accounting for the bracelets where there is a red bead opposite the blue bead and a symmetric arrangement of red and green beads on either side. These mirror image bracelets do not appear twice in the original list. The possible arrangements of the $3$ red and $6$ green beds in this interval is $\binom 93= 84$, and your division by $2$ discards half.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more term to add in the formula, accounting for all the necklaces which are [*chiral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(mathematics)), i.e. not rotationally identical to its mirror image. This is the distinction between counting distinct [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) and counting distinct bracelets (turnover-necklaces).

e.g. Here are the 3 distinct **bracelets** with 3 red and 3 green beads:

[image]

Note that the middle bracelet is chiral (there is no way to rotate it so that it equals its mirror image), so there are 4 distinct **necklaces** (turnover-bracelets) in total.